# How to join two tables - When there is multiple values in primary key column that you will use for JOIN

Tags: postgresql

I would like to join following two tables

USERS:

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | John |
| 13 | Brian |
| 14 | Steve |
| 15 | Barry |

VISITS:

| user_id | visited_page |
| --- | --- |
| user_12 | gasvhs |
| user_12,user_14 | dfvjk |
| user_15 | djvnjv |
| user_14,user_15 | sdhjcb |

EXPECTED RESULTS:

| visited_page | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| gasvhs | John |
| dfvjk | John;Steve |
| djvnjv | Barry |
| sdhjcb | Steve;Barry |

By using the following query, I'm getting the below shown result

**Query I wrote:**

```
SELECT visited_page, user_name
FROM VISITS
JOIN 
USERS on substring(user_id::VARCHAR FROM '[0-9]+')::INT = users.user_id
```

RESULTS I GOT:

| visited_page | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| gasvhs | John |
| dfvjk | John |
| djvnjv | Barry |
| sdhjcb | Steve |

Any suggestions on How to get the expected results ?

Comment: Please do not post links to pictures here. And please also do not include the pictures directly. It is best practice here on SO to post all your data as text (usually in code-blocks using triple-backticks). Please rework your question, thank you.

Comment: What's with that `substring(user_id::VARCHAR FROM '[0-9]+')::INT`? Why is `visits.user_id`  not an integer column?

Comment: It's not really clear how you arrive at that expected result. You have four users, and exactly one visit by each of them, in your example data.

Comment: Hi @Berhi - It's a visits.user_id is a TEXT.

Comment: Sorry guys. The sample data I provided had some issues and I just fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great example of why storing a comma separated list is such a very very bad idea.That being bad enough why would you ever prefix the user_id with a text string? :(. The first thing is to unroll visits.user_id to individual rows then strip off the prefix. The result being what the `visits` table should have been in the first place (less the mandatory FK of course).

```
select (replace(user_id,'user_',''))::integer user_id,visited_page
  from ( select unnest(string_to_array(user_id, ',')) user_id, visited_page  
           from visits
       ) s;
```

With that in place we can JOIN it to users, and aggregate user_name by page; Giving a final query: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8236270d8ead297c0b38adbf37c18a88))

```
select v.visited_page
     , string_agg( u.user_name, ',' order by u.user_name) users_visiting
  from users u
  join( select (replace(user_id,'user_',''))::integer user_id,visited_page
          from ( select unnest(string_to_array(user_id, ',')) user_id, visited_page  
                   from visits
                ) s
           ) v
      on (v.user_id = u.user_id) 
group by v.visited_page
order by v.visited_page;
```

Suggestion: Normalize the tables and do not store lists. This will result in easier queries, better performance, and provide data integrity. Consider what happens with the current schema had the user id simply been transposed (a potentially extremely common error) as 41 instead of 14 and user 41 did not exist.  And do not create unnecessary prefixes to data values to tell you what it is, the name already does that - at least if you choose good names and are consistent. But those are topics for a different day.